# Bash script, echo background color changes after ssh is started

Tags: bash

I have a script that looks like the following

```
echo -e "\033[1;41;97m";
echo "*   ";
echo "* Deploying on $con";
echo -e "*   \033[0m";
# Until this point, everything is rendered as expected

ssh -t -t "$con" << EOF
# After ssh has initiated the background is no longer as expected (see description and screenshots)
    ... remote commands ...
    exit;
EOF
```

When starts running I get the colors as expected - three lines with background red colour and white foreground color looking like this:

[image: Screenshot 1]

The moment the script reaches the ssh part, the background color of the already printed lines gets modified and looks like this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

The ssh is to an [Ubuntu Linux 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) running on [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services).

The script is running on OS X using [iTerm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2).

If I remove the `-t -t` from the ssh command then the behavior of the colors is as expected. However if I do that then sometimes the commands will not properly run. I have noticed that thus far this happens when system reports security upgrades are available.
Also, in that case I get the following message
"Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

What might be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Is the same shell / term used in both cases ?
You can check with

    `echo $0`
    `echo $TERM`

Comment: The value of `$TERM` is irrelevant.  What matters is the terminal (program) on the local side, and the actual characters which are sent to it.  The two pictures are not consistent (there is some text at the bottom of the first which is not accounted for).  Perhaps the local terminal is something like Eclipse's terminal (limited functionality, erratic).

Comment: The host is OSX and console client is iterm. If I remove the -t -t from the ssh command then the behavior is as expected. However, this sometimes results in the remote commands will not run (usually when system says it has pending security upgrades). Also, if I remove the -t -t then I get "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal."

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the `-t` by putting your commands on a single line separated by semicolons instead of using stdin. `ssh "$con" "command1;command2"`. The `exit` command is not necessary. The colours don't change either way for me, though I use Terminal.app.